# Is there a way to find out what version of Java an applet was compiled in

Tags: java, html, applet

I have an older applet I built. It naturally will not run in the browsers today.
Is there a way to find out what version of Java it was compiled in.

Also, what version of Java can i use so that my clients do not get that annoying security message, "are you sure you ant to run this"

Thirdly, will HTML5 with canvas be a better choice for the applet since it really just paints a pretty grid of images?

Comment: Already answered, but you might try decoding the .class file with a simple java class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736163/unsupportedclassversionerror-jdks-have-same-version

Comment: *"I have an older applet I built. It naturally will not run in the browsers today."*  Why not?  Because it is not digitally signed?  *"Also, what version of Java can i use so that my clients do not get that annoying security message"*  No version that is currently supported.  *"Thirdly, will HTML5 with canvas be a better choice for the applet since it really just paints a pretty grid of images?"*  Definitely yes.

Comment: I don't know why it stopped running. It was from 2009 and it just stopped displaying and gave a broken icon. I don't know about digitally signed. Back then I don't even know if we sis that since it doesn't sound familiar. It was my first real Java applet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack the jar and check the MANIFEST file.  It should have a header in there saying what version of java was used.

Example META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: jleibiusky
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_22
```

**Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_22** is the bit that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have a manifest you can use the [ClassVersionChecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293308/java-api-to-find-out-the-jdk-version-a-class-file-is-compiled-for), use [javap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file) or a [hex editor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698129/how-can-i-find-the-target-java-version-for-a-compiled-class)
2. The [changes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html) have been introduced since Java 7u21 (6u45 and and 5u45). So any version before that will do. However from a security perspective it is not wise to run such an old version!
3. Yes, definitly.